# How to start an Activity without opening parent's activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I made a Activity without any GUI.
The Activity shows my custom dialog.
In this way, I could obtain dialog-from-notification.
(The Activity is started by my app's notification.)

However, the problem is, If my application is alive at the background, other activity of my application shows up and then my dialog.

Is there any any FLAG I can use?

I already tried:

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME
FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

Answer (score 1):

try flag : Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
it will launch activity